# One part of JSON data being interpreted as an object and an similar part being interpreted as an array: why?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a php script that outputs `text/json` with the following output:

```
{"labels":{"ftemp":"Full time employment only","ptemp":"Part time employment only","study":"Further study only","workstudy":"Work and Study","noavail":"Not available for work","noemp":"Unemployed","other":"Other","refusal":"Information Refused"},"employjobs":{"Cambridge Beds Co Ltd.":"Accounts Assistant","Chinese Company":"Accountant"}}
```

Formatted more nicely it looks like this:

```
{
    "labels":
    {
        "ftemp":"Full time employment only",
        "ptemp":"Part time employment only",
        "study":"Further study only",
        "workstudy":"Work and Study",
        "noavail":"Not available for work",
        "noemp":"Unemployed",
        "other":"Other",
        "refusal":"Information Refused"
    },
    "employjobs":
    {
        "Cambridge Beds Co Ltd.":"Accounts Assistant",
        "Chinese Company":"Accountant"
    }
}
```

Now, to me both 'labels' and 'employjobs' look like they're both json objects with key-value pairs. However, when I make a JQuery getJSON call to the script, in the data object that is returned 'labels' is an object but 'employjobs' is an empty array.

What am I missing? The format of both bits of the json string look the same so why is one being interpreted as an object and the other as an empty array?

Any help very gratefully received, Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
here is the output of print_r for the data in the PHP script just before it goes through the json_encode function:

```
Array
(
    [labels] => Array
        (
            [ftemp] => Full time employment only
            [ptemp] => Part time employment only
            [study] => Further study only
            [workstudy] => Work and Study
            [noavail] => Not available for work
            [noemp] => Unemployed
            [other] => Other
            [refusal] => Information Refused
        )

    [employjobs] => Array
        (
            [Cambridge Beds Co Ltd.] => Accounts Assistant
            [Chinese Company] => Accountant
        )

)
```

As you can see, both 'labels' and 'employjobs' are key-value pair arrays and this is reflected in the JSON string output by the PHP script.

Comment: Did try to view the JSON object in the console ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm using to examine the object.

Comment: Here's the output from the console in WebKit Inspector:

`Object {labels: Object, employjobs: Array[0]}
employjobs: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
labels: Object
ftemp: "Full time employment only"
noavail: "Not available for work"
noemp: "Unemployed"
other: "Other"
ptemp: "Part time employment only"
refusal: "Information Refused"
study: "Further study only"
workstudy: "Work and Study"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Must be an error php-side, re-check your php code

Comment: Thanks, I will check the PHP again. However, the JSON string above is definitely what is output by the script as I've opened the script URL directly in the browser and the employjobs object is populated, which is what was stumping me. If the JSON string does contain the name value pairs, why are they not being picked up?

Appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: `If the JSON string does contain the name value pairs, why are they not being picked up?` logical deduction says they aren't populated - because parsing json doesn't mutate data, it's either valid and you get what's in the string, or it's not and you get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`employjobs` is probably empty under certain circumstances.  If it should never be empty, you  need to look into that.  If it's valid for it to be empty, php will omit empty array syntax for JSON by default.  If this is undesirable (i.e. you want an empty object) you can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option for `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This will be omitted as

```
'{"labels": "object with various values", "employjobs": {}}'
```

Comment: Thank you - this does the job of making employjobs an object. Now I just have to work out why the object is empty despite the JSON string having two entries for it when I open the php script in the browser. Thanks you very much for your help.